# Does $\mathbb{Z}_2$ act freely on $S^n \times S^m$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I was wondering whether the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_2$ acts freely on  $S^n \times S^m$ where $n,m\geq 2$? It seems to me that it does not act freely.

I know by Hatcher's book that there are two conditions that a finite group $G$ acting freely on $S^n$ must satisfy:

(a) Every abelian subgroup of $G$ is cyclic. This is equivalent to saying that $G$ contains
no subgroup $\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p$ with $p$ prime.

(b) $G$ contains at most one element of order 2.

Thus the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_2$ acts freely on  $S^n$. But my question is about $S^n\times S^m$ where $n,m\geq 2$.

Comment: $(x,y) \mapsto (-x, -y)$

Comment: Also $(x, y) \mapsto (-x, y)$ is a free action. In general, if $G$ acts freely on $M$, then $G$ acts freely on $M\times N$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese You are right. Thanks very much for the comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surely the answer is that $\mathbb Z_2$ **does** act freely on $S^n \times S^m$?

Let $e$ and $\sigma$ be the two elements of $\mathbb Z_2$ (with $e$ being the identity element). Suppose that the action of $\mathbb Z_2$ on $S^n \times S^m$ is given by
$$ e \ : \ (x, y) \mapsto (x, y), \qquad \qquad \sigma \ : \ (x, y) \mapsto (-x, -y), $$
where $-x \in S^n$ and $-y \in S^m$ are antipodal to $x \in S^n$ and $y \in S^m$ respectively.

Clearly, what I've written down is a free group action.

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice answer.